# How do I add a dark mode option in a ListView?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-dark-theme

I have a ListView with the app's more technical details and I want to implement a dark theme manual switch like this:
[image]

If it helps, here's the OnClickListener I use:

```
aboutListView.setOnItemClickListener((parent, view, i, id) -> {
    if (i == 0) {
       ConnectivityManager connectivityManager1 = (ConnectivityManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo networkInfo1 = connectivityManager1.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (networkInfo1 == null || !networkInfo1.isConnected() || !networkInfo1.isAvailable()) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainList.this, no_network.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();

        } else {
            String url = "https://example.com/";
            CustomTabsIntent.Builder builder = new CustomTabsIntent.Builder()
                    .setShareState(CustomTabsIntent.SHARE_STATE_OFF);
            CustomTabsIntent customTabsIntent = builder.build();
            customTabsIntent.launchUrl(this, Uri.parse(url));
        }

    } else if (i == 1) {
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager1 = (ConnectivityManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo networkInfo1 = connectivityManager1.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (networkInfo1 == null || !networkInfo1.isConnected() || !networkInfo1.isAvailable()) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainList.this, no_network.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        } else {
            String url = "https://example.com/";
            CustomTabsIntent.Builder builder = new CustomTabsIntent.Builder()
                    .setShareState(CustomTabsIntent.SHARE_STATE_OFF);
            CustomTabsIntent customTabsIntent = builder.build();
            customTabsIntent.launchUrl(this, Uri.parse(url));
        }
    }

});
```

Is there a simple way to do it?

Comment: please provide some details as to what have you tried, what is compulsory in your code and what is it you want to change. If you just want a review of your code, please post it at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example, you can add [MaterialAlertDialogBuilder](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/dialog/MaterialAlertDialogBuilder) when the user press on [Dark Theme]
and choose one from [ Day, DarkNight or System Default ]

And here is the code using [AppCompatDelegate](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/appcompat/app/AppCompatDelegate) to control switching between different themes:

Light / Day:

```
AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO)
```

Night Mode:

```
AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES)
```

System Default:

```
AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_FOLLOW_SYSTEM)
```

Don't forget which user choose.. for example to Shared Preference or any offline storage, to restore theme prefered to user when open app again.

Comment: Thanks! Now i have t work on the Shared Preferences.